# Getting individuals keys replaced on netbook

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure, netbook

Just today during a freak accident, a book got tossed onto my Samsung N120 netbook while it was open and the 'G' and 'T' key flew off. Part of the plastic underneath broke off.

Or would it be better to replace the entire keyboard?

**EDIT1**: Assuming I need to replace the entire keyboard, would I have to ask the manufacturer for an OEM one or are there other places where I can look?

**SOLUTION:** Samsung has pointed me to a supplier for a full keyboard replacement.

Comment: replacing the whole keyboard will be better. I think so

Comment: Leaning towards closing as this amounts to a shopping question unless you change it to not be so.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't get answered, I won't get pointed in any direction whatsoever. Part of the question has been answered anyways. Also, I'm asking this more in a general sense...

Comment: duct tape!!!! or super glue or get a new keyboard,  either that or pick up a simular netbook off ebay or craigslist

Comment: New keyboard is what I'm going for now... just where? Manufacturer or some other supplier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notebook/netbooks are usually "made up" of standardized parts, keyboard being one of them ... I haven't had the chance to try your netbook model, but I'd bet it comes with a keyboard like all other. A flat plastic, connected with one cable to the interface.

So, getting/replacing the keyboard is a better option, yeah.

Comment: Hmph, but if only two keys are damaged, do you know where I could get just the keys?

Comment: @Wesley - The thing is, I don't think you can get individual keys. Do the ones that have fallen off look like they can be reattached easily (from which you can deduct whether you can get individual replacable ones, but I doubt it).

Comment: They have been reattached, but are prone to fall off again.